# Cython Passing Classes to_py_call_code error

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am attempting to wrap two C++ classes using cython 0.25.2 (conda-forge build).  Have them defined as:

```
cdef extern from "Isd.h" namespace "csm":
    cdef cppclass CppIsd "csm::Isd":
        Isd() except +

cdef extern from "MdisPlugin.h":
    cdef cppclass CppMdisPlugin "MdisPlugin":
        MdisPlugin() except +
        string getPluginName()
        string getManufacturer()
        string getReleaseDate()
        string getCsmVersion
        size_t getNumModels()
        string getModelName(size_t modelIndex)
        bool canModelBeConstructedFromISD(const CppIsd &isd, const string &modelname)
        string convertISDToModelState(const CppIsd &isd, const string &modelname)
```

The Isd class is just a stub, exposed as:

```
cdef class Isd:
    cdef unique_ptr[CppIsd] thisptr
    def __init__(self):
        self.thisptr.reset(new CppIsd())
```

The final 2 methods of the CppMdisPlugin are throwing the following:  AttributeError: 'ErrorType' object has no attribute 'to_py_call_code' (Line 12552 in ExprNodes.py).

The minimal wrapper code is:

```
cdef class MdisPlugin:
    cdef:
        unique_ptr[CppMdisPlugin] thisptr

    def __init__(self):
        self.thisptr.reset(new CppMdisPlugin())

    def from_isd(self, Isd isd, modelname):
        return deref(self.thisptr).convertISDToModelState(deref(isd.thisptr), modelname)
```

Is the error being raised caused by a miss definition in the .pyx file or something happening internal to Cython?

Comment: It's Cython getting confused (so it's giving you an internal error instead of a useful error message), but it's probably something you've done. I'd guess the problem is with `modelname` - try creating a `std::string` temporary variable. (That is a guess though)

Comment: Your code works for me on Cython 0.23.4 (which is a little old now) once I've added the relevant standard library cimports. So I don't know what the issue is.